# How do I rename an illegally long filename to be short enough to use normally?

Tags: windows-7, filenames

I have a file with a very long filename (in excess of the 255 char limit) copied onto a FAT32 ubs stick from a power mac.

How can I rename it to be less the 255 chars?

Answer (score 1):

I realised in the end that Macs have the same limit so it had to be created somehow. I renamed the containing directory to a single letter and then dragged the directory to the root of the drive. I could then edit the filenames using windows explorer. Job done.

Answer (score 0):

Haven't tested it myself, but read that this little program should do the trick:
http://www.replsoft.com/cutlongnames.html

Comment: Thx. I wasn't really up for spending $30 until I had no other option. Eventually I figured it out.