# Cannot rename a file with name too long (no 8+3 name)

Tags: windows-10, cmd.exe, rename

I copied some directories from a now-defunct Mac laptop. I am trying to open one of the files (a PDF), but Acrobat won't open it because the name is too long.

I am trying to rename the file to a shorter name, but I cannot. Explorer won't let me, again, because of the long name.

I tried renaming it in cmd.exe using the 8+3 name, but none of the files from Mac have 8+3 names. That means that there is no way to rename it using the short name.

What else I can do?

Comment: https://superuser.com/q/755298/565702

Comment: https://superuser.com/q/78434/241386

Comment: The problem is the files don't have short names, so the solutions for that article don't work for me.

Comment: Then you have to shorten the names of the folders and files. That is the solution.

Comment: @Miguel where in the other answers say that the only way is to use the 8.3 name? Did you read any of the duplicate questions? There are various solutions like [subst the folder to a drive character, create a soft link or simply append `\\?\\` to the path](https://superuser.com/a/811155/241386)

Answer (score 1):

An annoying run around is to use a live cd, such as parted magic. This will allow you to rename the file then copy as needed.

Comment: +0 for the annoying part

Comment: @Twisty  it is annoying. I'm not going to sugar coat it.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was a combination of zipping the directory with the file, then change the file name in the zip application. Then I used [robocopy](https://superuser.com/questions/45697/how-to-delete-a-file-in-windows-with-a-too-long-filename) to remove the old file.

Thanks everyone for the help!