# remove duplicate words in file name

Tags: powershell

Batch delete duplicate words in file name
the code is posted in the this post, but it does not work with me
[Deleting repeated parts of a file name?](https://superuser.com/questions/1263768/deleting-repeated-parts-of-a-file-name)

```
Get-ChildItem -Path .\* -File -Recurse | ForEach-Object {
    Rename-Item $_ -NewName ((($_.Basename.Split("_") | Select-Object -Unique) -Join "_") + $($_.Extension))
}
```

Comment: What exactly does not work? Do you get an error message? This code splits on _ is this good for your filenames? if you don't have an underscore anywhere, it won't do anything

Comment: Try: `(Get-ChildItem -Path .\* -File -Recurse) | Rename-Item -NewName { (@($_.BaseName.Split('_') | select -unique) -join '_') + $_.Extension } -WhatIf`.

Comment: does not work for files in sub folders and this appear: Rename-Item : Cannot rename because item at 'A1 A1.docx' does not exist.
At line:2 char:5
+     Rename-Item $_ -NewName ((($_.Basename.Split(" ").ToUpper() | Sel ...
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Rename-Item], PSInvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidOperation,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RenameItemCommand

Comment: That is not the code @KeithMiller gave you..

Comment: @Theo: Thank you! m26348762: EDIT YOUR QUIESTION! Add sample filenames, formatted CORRECTED code, and error messages to your edited question...